# django How to optimize sql statement?

Tags: python, mysql, django

my code:
i use django orm

```
dynasty_li = ["USA", 'US', 'JPN']

data={}
for dynasty in dynasty_li:
    data[dynasty]=People.objects.filter(dynasty=dynasty).order_by("-create_time")[:100]
```

if use sql

```
dynasty_li = ["USA", 'US', 'JPN']
data={}
for dynasty in dynasty_li:
    sql="select * from people group by dynast='{dynast}' order by create_time DESC"
    data[dynasty]=query(sql)
```

I think it should be group by, but it is impossible to extract the top N from the bottom based on each dynasty
I improved my sql statement

```
SELECT a.id,a.name,a.dynasty,a.create_time FROM people a
left OUTER join people b
on (a.dynasty=b.dynasty and a.id<b.id)
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING count(*)<4
ORDER BY dynasty,create_time
```

But the execution time is relatively long, there are only less than 10,000 pieces of data, and the execution time is 10s

How to be more pythonic?

Comment: if Dynasty and People are different models, you use prefetch_related on Dynasty model.

Comment: no, is same model

Answer (score 0):

What is the goal?  What happened to the list of country codes?  How many rows do you expect in the output?  3?  or 10K?

Maybe you want:

```
SELECT a.id,a.name,a.dynasty,a.create_time
    FROM people a
    WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people b
               WHERE b.dynasty = a.dynasty
                 AND b.id > a.id
          ) > 4
    ORDER BY a.dynasty, a.create_time
```

Indexes:

```
INDEX(dynasty, id),
INDEX(dynasty, create_time)
```